# What is the proper resolution for tags hijacking?

Tags: discussion, tags

What to do when some tag was created with an obvious meaning, but later on took a different meaning entirely? For example, [.cdr](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.cdr) tag. It was created as "CorelDraw file extension", but later on used as "CD-R Disk" by two users.

I think the proper course of action is:

1. Create "cd-r" tag.
2. Retag two questions.
3. Add descriptions to both tags.

But I'm not sure, maybe if a tag took a new meaning, the original one does not matter?

Comment: I went ahead and performed the modifications above, so the "evidence" is not there anymore.

Comment: and of course, when in doubt the tag wiki takes precedence, so when creating a new tag, those would need to be filled up.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: I took care of that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### In this case

You're absolutely right, even though only a single question uses the tag as referring to the file extension.

The leading dot makes it clear that it refers to a file extension, so there's absolutely no way it could stand for something else (as long as there's no well-known Unix dot file, like [.bashrc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.bashrc), by that name). It's likely just an accident due to suggestions in tag name autocompletion.

### More generally

It depends on what is considered on-topic on the site, and what's the more common interpretation *on this site*. We recently had this with [kvm](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/kvm), which usually stood for keyboard/video/mouse switches, but more recently also stands for [kernel-based virtual machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel-based_Virtual_Machine). Ubuntu.SE or Unix.SE will most likely judge differently.

It's not always what was earlier though: I believe virtual memory is (at least in consumer computing) older than virtual machines, but uses of [vm](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vm) almost always refer to the latter.

I also remember a discussion about [sas](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sas) (Serial Attached SCSI and a statistics program). Questions about either are usually better suited for other Stack sites though.

---

It's possible that a (rarely used) tag has its meaning changed when a new technology or product comes along, especially if there's no tag wiki. But the community of Meta.SU must decide about ambiguous tags case by case.

Comment: [More recent example](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3682/mono-tag-as-in-vs-net-and-as-in-vs-stereo), with at least 8 questions asked about the .NET implementation before the first audio question came along. In this case, using *mono-framework* for the .NET implementation questions probably makes sense.