# "mono" tag as in "vs .net" and as in "vs. stereo"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, tags

There seem to be two uses of the tag "mono", one for questions related to audio and one for questions related to the Mono framework.

Wouldn't it be better to create a tag "mono-framework" and retag all questions (it's a dozen or so)?

Answer (score 11):

Yes, [mono](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mono) contains 39 questions, so it should be easy to just retag those about the Mono framework to [mono-framework](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mono-framework) and leave [mono](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mono) for audio.

If these are more than 10 questions, you shold probably consider not editing them all at once to avoid cluttering the front page.

Comment: I hope someone with enough reputation to retag reads this and agrees. :-)

Comment: @AndrewJ.Brehm Retagging [requires 500 reputation](http://superuser.com/privileges/retag-questions) ;)

Comment: Oh, ok. I'll start then.

Comment: Missed the hint about not editing them all at once. Cluttered the front page. :-(

Comment: @AndrewJ.Brehm While I support this effort, it's hardly urgent and a single answer with two or three up votes isn't exactly community consensus (yet). In the future, you probably should wait a day or so before acting on a Meta topic.

Comment: I didn't see you were starting, so sorry if you didn't know it was better to wait a bit before re-tagging. @and

Comment: Actually, I thought this should be done as quickly as possible, since there were only few questions now and maybe new questions will use the new tag now. How many votes would indicate community consensus?

Comment: That's hard to say, but in general, you should maybe wait one or two days, until you can see if there's a good agreement (like here, 6/8 votes) or people post a valid counter-argument. For example [this proposal](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3681/consolidating-adding-synonyms-for-cron-crontab-cronjob-tags) still only has 2 votes.