# Audio tags cleanup

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

There are a bunch of audio-related tags. In a quick search, I found [5.1](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/5.1), [surround-sound](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/surround-sound), [stereo](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/stereo), [audio](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/audio), [mono](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mono), [audio-output](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/audio-output), [static](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/static) and [clicking-sound](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/clicking-sound).

As per it's tag description, [mono](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mono) is meant for audio-related questions, however it keeps getting used for [mono-framework](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mono-framework) as well. Obviously a tag cleanup would solve the immediate issue, however this [has happened before](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3682/mono-tag-as-in-vs-net-and-as-in-vs-stereo?rq=1).

#### What I propose:

- **Burn** [clicking-sound](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/clicking-sound), <strike>static</strike> Done!
- **Merge and Synonymise** [stereo](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/stereo)[5.1](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/5.1)[surround-sound](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/surround-sound) -> [audio-output](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/audio-output)
- **Retag** [mono](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mono) audio questions appropriately
- **Synonymise** [mono](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mono) -> [mono-framework](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mono-framework)
- **Retag/Clean** [audio](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/audio) and [digital-audio](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/digital-audio)  - We have [audio-recording](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/audio-recording) [audio-conversion](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/audio-conversion) [audio-output](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/audio-output) and [audio-streaming](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/audio-streaming), we should be using them

Thoughts?

Answer (score 11):

If we do this the way you want, it would be like fighting against the tide. I would rather remove [mono](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mono) or at least merge it with [mono-framework](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mono-framework) (after cleaning) and drop the usage of [mono](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mono) as single channel sound (is that even useful?).

Comment: I agree regarding single channel sound. It should be replaced with `audio` or something similar. `mono` should be synonymous with `mono-framework`.

Comment: Sounds good to me, I've edited my question

Comment: Hmm, I've gone deeper into the rabbit hole and also found [stereo], [5.1], [clicking-sound], [surround-sound] and [audio]. I'm gonna edit my question to reflect this

Answer (score 3):

Why not rename `mono` to `mono-audio` tag? This way in the future no one will think of using this tag when asking a question related to `mono-framework`.

Comment: I did actually have this as a suggestion, but based on upvotes/comments on Braiam's answer I changed it.

Comment: Well, if `mono` tag for audio meaning is useful today, then why should it be trashed? It would be more useful to simply rename it into something less ambiguous..

Comment: Exactly what difference there is between some mono channel audio and stereo audio? IMO, that kind of information is worthless to categorize a question and I doubt anyone would try to find a question about mono audio (any mono audio experts around?)

Comment: I'm in agreement with @Braiam. I've also found other tags that need cleanup. See my edited question